# Will all currently installed PHP versions work after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, php

I have currently 2 versions of PHP (7.1 & 5.6) installed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm going to upgrade Ubuntu to 18.04 LTS. Will this upgrade caused any problem for my PHPs?